# generating a link while retrieve list of files and folders in dropbox using dcblog laravel dropbox

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox

I am using an package called [laravel-dropbox](https://github.com/dcblogdev/laravel-dropbox). I am using it and find very helpful too. But now I am in a little bit trouble while I need to generate the link of files so that I can show the images which I have been uploaded so it will be better I will get the all files and folder with their links then it will me a lot. Currently I am getting all the files and folders and its working fine from below method

```
return \Dcblogdev\Dropbox\Facades\Dropbox::files()->listContents($query);
```

like after using this method I am getting the following output
[image]

but here I dont get the links so that I can't show the uploaded images to my website. So, please help me so that I can show user the uploaded images of dropbox into my website like below response
[image]

Please Help me to get the desired result